# These 2 line of codes are almost exactly the same and yet they produce different result

Tags: vb.net

I wrote a code to access hitbtc API. It doesn't work. I copied the code that's available from hitbtc. It works. I want to see what went wrong with my original code. So I put the code side by side. In fact, to make sure there is no misunderstanding, slowly I change the correct code from hitbtc and replace that with variables computed from the wrong code.

The result is different.

The first code still fails. The second code is working.

I have no idea why.

Just look at these. It's the same code. That uses exact same variables used like once.

```
    Dim nonce = exchanges.getNonce().ToString
```

This code doesn't work

```
    Dim wc = New RestClient("https://api.hitbtc.com")
    Dim request = New RestRequest("/api/1/trading/balance", Method.GET)
    request.AddParameter("nonce", nonce)
    request.AddParameter("apikey", _apiKey)
    Dim texttobeSigned = wc.BuildUri(request).PathAndQuery()
    Dim sigHash2 = CalculateSignature1(texttobeSigned, _secret)
    request.AddParameter("X-Signature", sigHash2)
    Dim response = wc.Execute(request)
    'Dim sigsig1 = String.Concat(hasher.Hash.Select(Function(x) x.ToString("x2")).ToArray())
    Dim content = response.Content '"{"error":{"code":1001,"message":"Missing signature header parameter","description":""}}"
```

Right after that code, I do this. This one works.

```
    wc = New RestClient("https://api.hitbtc.com")
    request = New RestRequest("/api/1/trading/balance", Method.GET)
    request.AddParameter("nonce", nonce)
    request.AddParameter("apikey", _apiKey)
    request.AddHeader("X-Signature", sigHash2)
    response = wc.Execute(request)
    content = response.Content '{"balance":[{"currency_code":"1ST","cash":"0","reserved":"0"},{"currency_code":"8BT","cash":"0","reserved":"0"},{"
```

Comment: Copuld it possibly be because you're using the same `RestClient` twice in the first code? That's a complete stab in the dark but it's just about the only difference I can see.

Comment: In the first block, you're using `.AddParameter("X-Signature",..` while in the second one, you have `.AddHeader("X-Signature",..`.

Comment: AHHHHHHhhhh. That's the problem.

Comment: Please add that as answers and I will select that. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy-paste of the @Ahmes_Abdelhammed comment in order to allow you to close this question:

> In the first block, you're using .AddParameter("X-Signature",.. while in the second one, you have .AddHeader("X-Signature",..

Regards